# C# Is it possible to check if any specific digit is present in an ID?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to have a search option where

**1.user will type any letter that matches the name from database table.**

This works smoothly.

```
string userinput = "hel"

List<string> queryResult = _myContext.Products
  .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(userinput))
  .Select(r => r.Name)
  .ToList();
```

**2. user will type any digit that should match the ID if that digit/digits exist in the ID it should give me a list of those ID**

can i do something thing like that??

```
int queryId= 12;

_myContext.Products.Where(r => r.ID.contains(queryId)).Select(r => r.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: You'd have to convert both to strings to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string queryId = "12";

List<string> queryResult = _myContext.Products
  .Where(r => r.Id.Tostring().Contains(queryId))
  .Select(r => r.ID)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: As far I know `ToString` is not supported by EF, you should check that.

Comment: Apart from what @octa says, I think I've asked you this before, but could you please add some explanation to your answers instead of dumping "fixed" code and letting the OP and later visitors figure out what you changed?

Comment: @CodeCaster I edited my answer

Comment: You didn't add any explanation. Anyway `Convert.ToString()` will give the same exception: that can't be converted to an SQL query.

Comment: @CodeCaster what about now ;)

Comment: You just copied the code from the duplicate, and there still is no explanation in your answer.

Comment: nope I didn't copy any thing I searched ToString for ef and came accross this

Comment: @CodeCaster You marked as duplicate but the answer is given here on in duplicate is not syntax correct.  Just marking duplicate wont solve peoples problem .

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani .Contains is not proper syntax in this situation.

Comment: @user I don't see incorrect syntax in the duplicate. You may not be able to copy-paste the code as-is, some thinking may be required. That doesn't not make it a duplicate.

Comment: SOLUTION :  string filter = "456";
var results = from e in myDbContext.Employees
  where e.Id.ToString().Contains(filter)
  select e;
 Since some guys are so much interested to mark question duplicate before giving some time others to provide some help . This solves my issue. but cant write as an answer. Hope this would help others.

Comment: @APALALA this question has been asked fifty times before, try searching the next time. This site does not exist to help everyone with their problem, it's supposed to be a library of common questions and answers. No need to answer the same question yet another time. Also, depending on your Entity Framework version and whatnot, the code you posted will either throw that `int.ToString()` is not supported, or pull in the entire table and execute the query in-memory. But whatever floats your boat, be angry at people who _actually_ try to help you.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I edited some part of your answer. accept it so that i can mark it as an answer. thanks for the help

Comment: oh you were the one who edited the answer? please edit it again ;)

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani did it again . :)